# Overlay images onto Camera preview SurfaceView

Tags: android, graphics, camera, surfaceview

I have a `SurfaceView` that is being used to draw images, and I would like to overlay them onto a live-feed from the phone's camera.

Currently, the `SurfaceView` that contains the images have a white-background, but if I were to overlay them onto the phone's camera feed, they would have to be transparent. The camera and animation drawing cannot be done on the same `SurfaceView`.

What is the best course to pursue the use of multiple views that involve managing the camera and drawing images? Is it possible to make a `SurfaceView` transparent?

Answer (score 20):

Well here's how I did it ... I hope somebody finds it useful though the Qualcomm AR stuff is out.. it might be obselete..
oh and basically what this does is -- generate two funky cubes from that Android Example, additional functionality introduced are the touch events, though the rotational vectors are off by a lot-- just for a demonstration purpose anyway and ofcourse the cubes overlaid on top of the camera preview which can be moved on a screen..

```
     public class TakeRecieptPicture extends Activity implements Callback {
    private Camera camera;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

    private TouchSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;

    ShutterCallback shutter = new ShutterCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onShutter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // No action to be perfomed on the Shutter callback.

        }

       };
    PictureCallback raw = new PictureCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // No action taken on the raw data. Only action taken on jpeg data.
      }

       };

    PictureCallback jpeg = new PictureCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try{
                outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/test.jpg");
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                Log.d("Camera", e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("Camera", e.getMessage());
            }

        }

       };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


         mGLSurfaceView = new TouchSurfaceView(this); 
     addContentView(mGLSurfaceView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
         addContentView(mSurfaceView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
       mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
       mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
       mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
       mSurfaceHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT|LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND); 
       }

    private void takePicture() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.takePicture(shutter, raw, jpeg);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
        p.setPreviewSize(arg2, arg3);
        try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(arg0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        camera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera = Camera.open();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
    }
    }
```

The TouchSurfaceView is defined below:

```
   class TouchSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {  

    public TouchSurfaceView(Context context) {       
        super(context); 
        cr  = new CubeRenderer(true);
        this.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        this.setRenderer(cr);
        this.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);  
        this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

        }  

    public boolean onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent e) {     
        cr.mAngleX += e.getX() * TRACKBALL_SCALE_FACTOR;      
        cr.mAngleY += e.getY() * TRACKBALL_SCALE_FACTOR;    
        requestRender();   
        return true;    }   

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {      
        float x = e.getX();       
        float y = e.getY();     
        switch (e.getAction()) {    
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:     
            float dx = x - mPreviousX;         
            float dy = y - mPreviousY;           
            cr.mAngleX += dx * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR;   
            cr.mAngleY += dy * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR;       
            requestRender();      
            }     
        mPreviousX = x;  
        mPreviousY = y;     
        return true;  

    }
    private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 180.0f / 320;  
    private final float TRACKBALL_SCALE_FACTOR = 36.0f;   
    public  CubeRenderer cr ;
    private float mPreviousX;   
    private float mPreviousY;


}
```

And the CubeRenderer is given by:

```
    class CubeRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {  
    public CubeRenderer(boolean useTranslucentBackground) { 
        mTranslucentBackground = useTranslucentBackground;   
        mCube = new Cube();  
       }  


    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {  
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     
        gl.glLoadIdentity();    
        gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -5.0f);  
        gl.glRotatef(mAngle,        0, 1, 0);  
        gl.glRotatef(mAngle*0.25f,  1, 0, 0);     
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); 
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);    
        mCube.draw(gl);      
        gl.glRotatef(mAngle*2.0f, 0, 1, 1);    
        gl.glTranslatef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);     
        mCube.draw(gl);     
        mAngle += 1.2f;  
        }  
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {     
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);    
        float ratio = (float) width / height;     
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);       
        gl.glLoadIdentity();     
        gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 10);
        } 

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {      

        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);     
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);   
        if (mTranslucentBackground) {          
            gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0);      
            } else {        
                gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);     
                }       
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);     
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);     
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);   
        }  

    public void setAngle(float _angle){

    }
    private boolean mTranslucentBackground;  
    private Cube mCube;  
    private float mAngle;
      public  float mAngleX;  
       public float mAngleY;

}
```

And finally the Cube itself is given by:

```
    class Cube{   
    public Cube()  
    {        int one = 0x10000;    
    int vertices[] = {  
            -one, -one, -one,   
            one, -one, -one,     
            one,  one, -one,      
            -one,  one, -one,           
            -one, -one,  one,         
            one, -one,  one,           
            one,  one,  one,          
            -one,  one,  one,        };  

    float[] colors = {      
            0f,    0f,    0f,  0.5f, 
            1f ,  0f,  0f, 0.1f,    
            1f,1f,0f,0.5f,   
            0f,  1f,    0f,  0.1f,      
            0f,    0f,  1f,  0.1f,       
            1f,    0f,  1f,  0.2f,      
            1f,  1f,  1f,  0.1f,        
            0f,  1f,  1f,  0.1f,        };    

    byte indices[] = {          
            0, 4, 5,    0, 5, 1,    
            1, 5, 6,    1, 6, 2,     
            2, 6, 7,    2, 7, 3,      
            3, 7, 4,    3, 4, 0,      
            4, 7, 6,    4, 6, 5,       
            3, 0, 1,    3, 1, 2        };   


    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length*4);   
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());     
    mVertexBuffer = vbb.asIntBuffer();    
    mVertexBuffer.put(vertices);      
    mVertexBuffer.position(0);      
    ByteBuffer cbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length*4);   
    cbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());     
    mColorBuffer = cbb.asFloatBuffer();      
    mColorBuffer.put(colors);     
    mColorBuffer.position(0);      
    mIndexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length);     
    mIndexBuffer.put(indices);     
    mIndexBuffer.position(0);    } 
    public void draw(GL10 gl)    {    
        gl.glFrontFace(gl.GL_CW);     
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, gl.GL_FIXED, 0, mVertexBuffer);  
        gl.glColorPointer(4, gl.GL_FIXED, 0, mColorBuffer);     
        gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, 36, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mIndexBuffer);    } 

    private IntBuffer   mVertexBuffer;  
    private FloatBuffer   mColorBuffer;   
    private ByteBuffer  mIndexBuffer;

    }
```

Well hope somebody finds this useful...

Comment: how do i change the camera angle? its rotated to -90degrees now.thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

I'm doing augmented application too and hit the same problem you hit. There is very few information on how to solve it right. But I found a framework called **mixare** - it allow you to create AR app for android. You should definitely look at it [source](http://github.com/mixare/mixare) - it looks pretty promising. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 6):

I have had success with the following approach.

First make a layout xml file that looks something like this (note the order of the two views):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.yourcustom.OverlayView
        android:id="@+id/overlay" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </com.yourcustom.OverlayView>

    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </SurfaceView>

</FrameLayout>
```

`OverlayView` is a subclass of `SurfaceView` with the drawing and animation thread implementations. The other SurfaceView will be the surface that handles the Camera preview. Inside of `onCreate` you should set up your views like this:

```
    mView = (OverlayView)this.findViewById(R.id.overlay);
    mView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT); 

    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)this.findViewById(R.id.surface);
    mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

You should add a `SurfaceHolder.Callback` implementation to the `SurfaceHolder` of `mView` that handles the animation thread. An example of implementing this within the subclass and using animation/drawing threads can be found in the old LunarLander example here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/src/com/example/android/lunarlander/LunarView.html

Besides that you set up the camera SurfaceView the same way as this example:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html

Comment: you forget to close <FrameLayout>

Comment: This is wrong because com.yourcustom.OverlayView needs to be the second in the Framelayout in order to be on the top...

Answer (score 1):

MIght [this code](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/6e1f453ac051f6bd?pli=1) help?`

Comment: My DrawonTop class also extends SurfaceView and implements the SurfaceHolder.Callback interface. Do you think that will cause me problems if I'm trying to overlay it over the Camera Preview? I read that SurfaceViews cannot be transparent, but I'm wondering whether that is just a bunch of hogwash.

Comment: In addition to this, doesn't the DrawOnTop class need to be called in some kind of UIthread? It isn't being done in the example you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a slightly strange aftershock from upgrading my handset to 4.0.4.  I have a translucent gl whole screen overlay on a whole screen camera preview, which worked quite happily on an earlier ics build (I think it was 4.0.3, but not certain). After upgrading to 4.0.4, the preview went a bit haywire, with the camera image showing psychedelic primary areas of colour on any of the brighter parts of the camera image (darker parts looked OK).  Eventually found that changing glclearcolour to 0,0,0,0 from 0.5, 0.5, 0.5. 0 sorted it out.

It seems that even though the alpha was zero on the unused parts of the gl overlay, the blending function was still taking account of the grey gl background.