# ZXing Barcode Reader: How to make custom border around capture screen?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, zxing

I want to put custom border around zxing capture screen (camera screen).  What modification would I need to make for this?  Which activity and layouts would I need to change to have this effect?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to edit layouts at all.

In `ViewfinderView` find `onDraw` method. It's the core that draws the "scanning rectangle". You can modify it the way you want.

The code that actually draws the rectangle can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/ViewfinderView.java#99):

```
// Draw the exterior (i.e. outside the framing rect) darkened
paint.setColor(resultBitmap != null ? resultColor : maskColor);
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, frame.top, paint);
canvas.drawRect(0, frame.top, frame.left, frame.bottom + 1, paint);
canvas.drawRect(frame.right + 1, frame.top, width, frame.bottom + 1, paint);
canvas.drawRect(0, frame.bottom + 1, width, height, paint);
```

Comment: I want to put a border around it.  Any clues on how I could use this modify the outer area that is not in scanning rectangle? How would I ID the area that is the scanning rectangle vs. the outer shell?  Also can I set vertical layout or is it always horizontally run?  Thanks

Comment: I've added direct link to the code that is responsible for the rectangle. You can replace code and draw whatever you want instead.

Comment: To allow portrait mode for scanner activity remove `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` from `CaptureActivity` definition in AndroidManifest (
http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/AndroidManifest.xml#41 ). But I would strongly recommend against it. Try it yourself and you will understand why.

Answer (score 6):

This question already has an answer. But if someone needs how to draw a border around capture screen, here is the code. inazaruk's answer is correct. My answer is just an extension for that.

```
 //initialize new paint in the constructor
 Paint borderPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
 borderPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));

 //inside onDraw
 int distance = (frame.bottom - frame.top) / 4;
 int thickness = 15;

 //top left corner
 canvas.drawRect(frame.left - thickness, frame.top - thickness, distance + frame.left, frame.top, borderPaint);
 canvas.drawRect(frame.left - thickness, frame.top, frame.left, distance + frame.top, borderPaint);

 //top right corner
 canvas.drawRect(frame.right - distance, frame.top - thickness, frame.right + thickness, frame.top, borderPaint);
 canvas.drawRect(frame.right, frame.top, frame.right + thickness, distance + frame.top, borderPaint);

 //bottom left corner
 canvas.drawRect(frame.left - thickness, frame.bottom, distance + frame.left, frame.bottom + thickness, borderPaint);
 canvas.drawRect(frame.left - thickness, frame.bottom - distance, frame.left, frame.bottom, borderPaint);

 //bottom right corner
 canvas.drawRect(frame.right - distance, frame.bottom, frame.right + thickness, frame.bottom + thickness, borderPaint);
 canvas.drawRect(frame.right, frame.bottom - distance, frame.right + thickness, frame.bottom, borderPaint);
```

[image]

Comment: how can you change the radius of the rectangles to make them rounded?

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548666/overlay-images-onto-camera-preview-surfaceview) is how a few others on SO did it.

Also look [here](http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/CameraTutorial), it looked useful.

Finally, I would use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933882/how-to-draw-an-overlay-on-a-surfaceview-used-by-camera-on-android) one.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can override the color in your own colors.xml file i.e.

```
<color name="viewfinder_border">#00d1cf</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomViewFinderView extends ViewFinderView {
        public CustomViewFinderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            setSquareViewFinder(true);
            setBorderColor(android.R.color.transparent);
            setMaskColor(android.R.color.transparent);
            setLaserColor(android.R.color.transparent);
        }
    }
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mImageViewOpenAlbum = rootview.findViewById(R.id.imv_OpenAlbumScanCamera);
        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions().transforms(new CenterCrop(), new RoundedCorners(10)); // size of the corner radius
        Glide.with(getContext())
                .load(dataPath)
                .apply(options)
                .into(mImageViewOpenAlbum);
        contentFrame = (ViewGroup) rootview.findViewById(R.id.content_frame);

        mImageViewFlash = rootview.findViewById(R.id.imv_FlashScanCamera);
        mImageViewQuestion = rootview.findViewById(R.id.imv_QuestionScanCamera);
        mImageViewOpenAlbum = rootview.findViewById(R.id.imv_OpenAlbumScanCamera);
        Uri allVideosUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(KEY.Shared_Preferences_Settings, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID};
        Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(allVideosUri, projection, null, null, null);

        try {
            cursor.moveToLast();
            do {
                dataPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            } while (dataPath.length() < 0);

            cursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Glide.with(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()))
                .load(dataPath)
                .apply(options)
                .into(mImageViewOpenAlbum);

        mImageViewQuestion.setOnClickListener(this);
        mImageViewFlash.setOnClickListener(this);
        mImageViewOpenAlbum.setOnClickListener(this);

        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getContext()) {
            @Override
            protected IViewFinder createViewFinderView(Context context) {
                return new CustomViewFinderView(context, null);
            }
        };
        contentFrame.addView(mScannerView);

// Здесь мы добавляем собственную рамку
        ImageView customFrame = new ImageView(getContext());
        customFrame.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_frame);
        customFrame.setScaleX(0.5f);    // уменьшить размер рамки на 50% по оси X
        customFrame.setScaleY(0.5f);    // уменьшить размер рамки на 50% по оси Y
        contentFrame.addView(customFrame);



    }
```