# Overlay a static drawable image over camera preview

Tags: android, android-widget, android-camera, surfaceview

I need to display a static .png image while my mobile is in the camera preview mode.As for now I am referencing this link [a link][Overlay images onto Camera preview SurfaceView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548666/overlay-images-onto-camera-preview-surfaceview) . and this link to display the camera preview screen[a link]http://android-er.blogspot.com.au/2010/12/add-overlay-on-camera-preview.html. Please suggest to proceed further.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Put the camera's preview SurfaceView and an ImageView into a FrameLayout or a RelativeLayout. The SurfaceView must be first in the layout and the ImageView second, so it is drawn above the SurfaceView.