# Add to Camera preview a frame showing position in Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I need to add to user interface in Android application using Camera API a frame showing ID card position with specific dimension on the screen, when the user is taking a picture.
like this:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: Simply use the solution provided for  *[Overlay a static drawable image over camera preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527943/overlay-a-static-drawable-image-over-camera-preview)*. You can use a PNG with transparency on top of the camera preview.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make your own camera and process each frame to find and highlight edges.
It's not an easy task :)

https://www.tensorflow.org/ or OpenCV might be of interest to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just need to add a frame that the user must 
respect it before the shoot, I didn't need an automatic detection of border

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant use android API (Android.Camera) for doing that. You can use the OpenCV to do anything in your application.