# How to record video with custom renderer on xamarin

Tags: xamarin

Can anyone help me with some documentation or example how to record video on xamarin.
I want to create an app to record video and to put some text on the video. on attach you can see the example[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBIib.jpg)

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Comment: Can you tell me its possible to put some text on video?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  https://www.raywenderlich.com/2734-avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Comment: Something for android

Comment: if it's an Android specific question you should tag it that way and probably mention it in your question.

Comment: @Aurel About add text on camera preview, I find one thread that you can take a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879403/how-to-add-text-on-camera-preview