# Overlay image On camera Feed

Tags: android

How can I overlay an image on camera Preview, Is there  any API or framework for this? I need to display a static image while my mobile is in the camera preview mode. I have tried it manually but it did not works.

Comment: Similar Q asked here - this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466336/android-overlay-on-android-camera-preview

Comment: and here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548666/overlay-images-onto-camera-preview-surfaceview