# How to write text on image using camera

Tags: android

How to merge text and image save in gallery.
How to write text on image using camera.

When put text on image can not save in image with text only save image how to solve this issue.

I have also fragment dialog for text get form the user in customize fragment.

```
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgCapture"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txvText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="84dp"
                    android:background="#66cecece"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Code :

```
   public void onUserSelectValue(String string) {
            if (string != null) {
                txvText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txvText.setText(string);
            } else
                txvText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            imgCapture.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you want to write text above the image is it? this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7328777/1697047 will help you

Comment: You should use SurfaceView like this exemple http://stackoverflow.com/a/3607264/2764682