# Display textview while recording video in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-video-record

I am trying to create a simple android app for recording video. I am able to get it working. But the video recording is coming in full screen. I want to add a textbox/ textview in the bottom section to show some text while the recording is in progress. Can somebody guide me on this.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this thread:

[Overlay images onto Camera preview SurfaceView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548666/overlay-images-onto-camera-preview-surfaceview)

Here is sample code:

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/12/add-overlay-on-camera-preview.html

Comment: The approach is correct and thanks for that. But I am facing issues while  adding the overlay. The aspect ratio is getting skewed, audio is not getting recorded.