# Display text above cameraView activity

Tags: android, android-camera

I would like to place a text above a cameraView activity. When the camera is opened, the text should be displayed on top as shown in the image below

exempled

[image]

Comment: use frame-layouts and you can achieve this functionality

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3607264/13533028 this is the solution you are looking for